# Change NSSearchField button cell image while typing

Tags: swift

I have a NSSearchField. I have added a custom image to the button cell using the following code:

```
extension NSSearchField{
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let cell = self.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell {
            if cell.identifier?.rawValue == "BaseSearchField"{
                cell.searchButtonCell?.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyDown
                cell.searchButtonCell?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SearchIcon-1")
                cell.searchButtonCell?.alternateImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SearchIcon-1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to change this image once the user starts typing in the search field.
I tried the following code:

```
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    if let searchField = obj.object as? NSSearchField{
        if searchField.stringValue != ""{
            if let cell = self.baseSearchField.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell {
                cell.searchButtonCell?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SearchIcon-2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the icon is not changing as soon I type in the search field. It changes only after I click out of the search field. Any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

A simple override fixed this issue for me

```
extension NSSearchField{
    open override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```